# Get value of the randomly chosen color

Tags: vba, solidworks, solidworksapi

I have a macro that colors the part or assembly. It randomly chooses the color and then apply it to the component. My problem is, I want to get the value of the randomly chosen color because I want that value in other sub, but I dont know how to get it. Could someone help me with this? Heres my code.

```
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Public Sub ColorMacro1()

 Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
 Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
 Dim swElement As Object
 Dim vElementArr As Variant
 Dim vElement As Variant
 Dim vMatProp As Variant

  Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
  Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    vMatProp = swModel.MaterialPropertyValues

'Get all elements
  If swModel.GetType = swDocPART Then
    vElementArr = swModel.GetBodies2(swAllBodies, False)
    For Each vElement In vElementArr
        Set swElement = vElement
        Randomize
        vMatProp(0) = Rnd 'Red
        vMatProp(1) = Rnd 'Green
        vMatProp(2) = Rnd 'Blue
        vMatProp(3) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Ambient
        vMatProp(4) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Diffuse
        vMatProp(5) = Rnd 'Specular
        vMatProp(6) = Rnd * 0.9 + 0.1 'Shininess
        swElement.MaterialPropertyValues2 = vMatProp
    Next
    
  ElseIf swModel.GetType = swDocASSEMBLY Then
    vElementArr = swModel.GetComponents(False)
    For Each vElement In vElementArr
        Set swElement = vElement
        Randomize
        vMatProp(0) = Rnd 'Red
        vMatProp(1) = Rnd 'Green
        vMatProp(2) = Rnd 'Blue
        
        vMatProp(3) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Ambient
        vMatProp(4) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Diffuse
        vMatProp(5) = Rnd 'Specular
        vMatProp(6) = Rnd * 0.9 + 0.1 'Shininess
        swElement.MaterialPropertyValues = vMatProp
        Next
    
  ElseIf swModel.GetType = swDocDRAWING Then
    MsgBox ("You can only apply random colors to part bodies or assembly components.")
    Exit Sub
    
  End If

 'Redraw to see new color
  swModel.GraphicsRedraw2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Declare `vMatProp` as a Public variable on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
Public vMatProp as Variant
```

2. Run the code you use, as it is. **Do not forget to delete the declaration from it**! Otherwise, it will not return an error, but **use its value only for this (existing) procedure**.
3. Use it in any other `Sub`, as it is...

Comment: Hi. thank you for your answer. 
Can I get the value of vMatProp by declaring another Dim like MyColor = vMatpro?
Please see codes below

Option explicit
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
Public vMatProp As Variant

   Public Sub ColorMacro1()

      Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
      Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
      Dim swElement As Object
      Dim vElementArr As Variant
      Dim vElement As Variant
      'Dim vMatProp As Variant
      Dim MyColor As Variant

 MyColor = vMatProp

Comment: @Mark donne: Posting code in a comment is not a good idea. I cannot understand it, but yes, if you have the `Public` `Variant` variable declared as I suggested you can declare another one inside of the new procedure. If you do not like using the existing one `vMatProp`, even if I cannot understand why, you can use: `Dim MyColor As Variant` and use it `MyColor = vMatProp`. But **they must be declared in exactly the same way**! Then you can use the new array exactly as you need.

Comment: Hi. Sorry about the codes in the comment. Im still learning in this site. I really appreciate your answer. I tried and it worked. hopefully I dont run into more errors with the other sub. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody help, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If somebody else search for a similar issue, he will know that the code works...

Comment: Done! I do have quick question, hope you could answer. 
How can I make this code to color only the selected assembly component?
`vElementArr = swModel.GetComponents(False)`